# Doesn't work TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag() in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I don't mind resetting the TrafficStats value before launching the application. For this I use TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag(), but TrafficStats does not clear.
I know that TrafficStats is being reset. happens when the phone is rebooted
It is possible to reset TrafficStats. via code

```
fun myNetvorkCheck(){
    checkNetworkConnection = CheckNetworkConnection(application)
    checkNetworkConnection.observe(this, { isConnected->
            if (isConnected) {
                checkTraficStart()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                checkTrafficEnd()
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    })
}

fun checkTraficStart() {
    //resetMobile()
    //total dowlaood bytes
    val dowladBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
    //total uload bytes
    val uploaBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()
    // only star mobile dowlaod bytes
    val startdowMobile = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
    //only start mobile upload bytes
    val startuploMobile = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()
    //convert bytes to Mb
    val finalmobDowload = ( startdowMobile ) / 1048576
    val finalmodUpload1 = ( startuploMobile ) / 1048576
    //total traffic za ves den
    val modileZaden = finalmobDowload + finalmodUpload1

    startmobileTraffic =  modileZaden.toInt()

    textDowload.text = finalmobDowload.toInt().toString()
    textUpload.text = finalmodUpload1.toInt().toString()
    txtInfo.text = modileZaden.toInt().toString()

}

fun checkTrafficEnd() {

    endmobileTraffic = endmobileTraffic + startmobileTraffic
    mobileVse = startmobileTraffic
    textObchiy.text = endmobileTraffic.toString()
    saveTrafic(mobileVse)
    saveTrafficAll(endmobileTraffic)
    resetMobile()
}


fun saveTrafic(res:Int) {
    val edit = traficPref?.edit()
    edit?.putInt("key",res)
    edit?.apply()
}

fun saveTrafficAll(res: Int){
    val alledit = traficPrefAll?.edit()
    alledit?.putInt("keyAll",res)
    alledit?.apply()
}

fun resetMobile() {
    TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag()
}
```

why   textDowload.text = 515
textUpload.text = 50
and not
textDowload.text = 0
textUpload.text = 0
????